# Uipicker Background color

Tags: iphone, ios4

I need help to change the background color of UIPicker in the center not border of picker with any specific image instead of default light sky blue background color. And i also want to change light transparent color strip which showing the selection of the picker value.

Thanks
Rana

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean with blue background color, but there's few things you can change on the UIPicker. To change the appearance of the selector, [you have to disable it and draw it yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466346/how-to-change-the-color-of-uipickerview-selector). And that's about it, you can't tweak its colors other than that.

**Edit:** Found a question that suggests a [workaround to do some custom coloring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965375/change-uipickerview-background).

Comment: Thanks for your help, actually i mean with blue background color is that when we are show any kind of elements in picker whose background layer is sky blue in the center i am not talking about the border of picker,i mean inside the picker. And i also want to change the selection layer in the center of picker.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example provided by Apple - [UICatalog Intro](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html)
look at custom tab of pickers.

Basically you need to style the view

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view;
```

Also have a look at [ALPickerView](https://github.com/alexleutgoeb/ALPickerView) could be useful if apple doc didn't help.

For the style of border, you better use image on top of picker, thats how i solved once.

HIH