# How to change the color of the selection indicator lines?

Tags: ios, uipickerview

The app that I am making uses a picker view that I customised using:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{

    UILabel* label = (UILabel*)view;
    if (!label)
    {
        label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:32]];
        label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.478431 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.numberOfLines= [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]count];
    }

    KTCategory *category = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] objectAtIndex:row];

    // Fill the label text here
    label.text= category.name;

    return label;
}
```

The background colour of the view is black and the selection indicator is no longer visible.  How can I make the indicator lines that show the selected row the same colour as my text?

Comment: try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466346/how-to-change-the-color-of-uipickerview-selector

Comment: @Ron Thanks Ron! What size should i make the image?