# Change the color of the lines in UIPickerView with Swift

Tags: swift, uipickerview

Basically I just want to change the color of the seperator lines:

[image]

I think for obj-c there is an answer here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466346/how-to-change-the-color-of-uipickerview-selector). But I have difficulties to translate it in Swift. How to do that?

Comment: Don't do it. If Apple wanted you to be able to modify / customize this feature of a UIPickerView, they would have provided API for doing so. Performing unsupported modifications of built-in interface classes can get your app rejected from the App Store.

Comment: there isn;t answer because they put a image on the foreground,but you want color,there is no color

Comment: Thanks for the answers. So this means Apple wants me to use UIPickerView only on light backgrounds?

Comment: Unbelievable ... we can't change the horizontal lines color?

Answer (score 0):

[Hi] you can do this,

```
pickerView.subviews[1].backgroundColor = UIColor.white
pickerView.subviews[2].backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```