# SwiftUI | Picker - Change selected row color

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to change the color of the selected row.

[image]

As you may see, by default it has this light gray color.

I have no idea how to do that since I have found no way to access this row at all.
Is there any way to do that?

Demo code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var data = Array(0...20).map { "\($0)" }
    @State private var selected = 0

    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("", selection: $selected) {
                ForEach(0 ..< data.count) {
                    Text(data[$0])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A UIKit answer would also be welcomed since I have found no way either.

Thank you!

Comment: This is a UIPickerView - read *Special Considerations* in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview/1614373-showsselectionindicator

Comment: Unfortunately, it's no longer here. iOS 7 to 13 only.

Comment: That's what I meant - you cannot change default selection in this control - create custom one if you don't like standard.

Comment: Haha it's all right, I've been able to customize it a bit and also found a workaround to somewhat set the color.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here would be a way to somewhat customize it.
The workaround is to just simply put a RoundedRectangle with the color of your choice perfectly underneath it.

It's not perfect, since the gray default opacity overlay is on top of that color and one has to figure out the constraints based on the frame.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var data = Array(0...20).map { "\($0)" }
    @State private var selected = 0

    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width-18, height: 32)
                .foregroundColor(.green)
            
            Picker("", selection: $selected) {
                ForEach(0 ..< data.count) {
                    Text(data[$0])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

## Using the Introspect Swift Package

It is not trivial to do in SwiftUI. I did some research however.
The underlying class behind SwiftUI's `Picker` goes back to `UIKit` and it is the `UIPickerView`. To customise its behaviour you need access then to the `UIPickerView` class and the documentation is somewhat severely lacking.
And looking at other posts on SO it seems that the way to configure the picker goes all the way to objC for example with the `setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String)` function. I could not even find a list of those keys! And trying to set up the color of the text did not work however... I found out that I can access the subviews and could solve this background color problem.

This is just to say that I think the best way I found is using this Swift Package called [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect).

These guys (and girls) did really an amazing job.

- First install the Swift Package in your project.
- Then add the code to introspect the UIPickerView. This is not part of the defaults so you need to create a custom extension like:

```swift
import Introspect

extension View {
    public func introspectUIPickerView(customize: @escaping (UIPickerView) -> ()) -> some View {
        return inject(UIKitIntrospectionView(
            selector: { introspectionView in
                guard let viewHost = Introspect.findViewHost(from: introspectionView) else {
                    return nil
                }
                return Introspect.previousSibling(containing: UIPickerView.self, from: viewHost)
            },
            customize: customize
        ))
    }
}
```

- In your code you have now access to the `UIPickerView`, the underlying UIKit class of your SwiftUI's `Picker`. Add this after the Picker:

```swift
Picker("Flavor", selection: $selectedFlavor) {
    ForEach(Flavor.allCases) { flavor in
        Text(flavor.rawValue.capitalized)
    }       
}
.pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle()
.introspectUIPickerView { picker in
    picker.subviews[1].backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}
```

I used the Picker example from the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/picker) and added the `.introspectUIPickerView` modifier.
The result: no more grey highlighted color.

Not everything will work because the UIPickerView is really old and some things are not easily customisable. So if you want to customise other things your mileage might vary :)

Here in red with :

```swift
.introspectUIPickerView { picker in
                picker.subviews[1].backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                   .withAlphaComponent(0.2)
            }
```

[image: exampleWithRed]

Comment: replacing `return Introspect.previousSibling(containing: UIPickerView.self, from: viewHost)` 
with  `return Introspect.findAncestorOrAncestorChild(ofType: UIPickerView.self, from: viewHost)` 
worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a pure SwiftUI picker implementation

[MyPickerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCarF.png)

```
struct MyPickerView<T: Equatable>: View {
    
    let options: [T]
    @Binding var selection: T
    @SwiftUI.State private var drag: Double = 0
    let cellAngles = 20.0
    let presentation: (T) -> String
    
    init(_ options: [T], _ selection: Binding<T>, _ presentation: @escaping (T) -> String = {"\($0)"}) {
        self.options = options
        self._selection = selection
        self.presentation = presentation
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        let selectedIndex = getSelectedIndex()
        HStack {
            ZStack {
                ForEach(0..<options.count, id: \.self) { index in
                    let item: T = options[index]
                    MyPickerCell(title: presentation(item), angle: Double(index - selectedIndex) * cellAngles + drag)
                }
                Color.gray.opacity(0.1)
                    .frame(height: 1)
                    .offset(y: 15)
                Color.gray.opacity(0.1)
                    .frame(height: 1)
                    .offset(y: -15)
            }
            .frame(width: 100, height: 200)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { gesture in
                        drag = gesture.translation.height
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        var newIndex = selectedIndex - Int(round(drag / cellAngles))
                        if newIndex < 0 {
                            newIndex = 0
                        }
                        if newIndex >= options.count - 1 {
                            newIndex = options.count - 1
                        }
                        selection = options[newIndex]
                        drag = 0
                    }
            )
        }
    }
    
    func getSelectedIndex() -> Int {
        return options.firstIndex(of: selection) ?? 0
    }
    
}

private struct MyPickerCell: View {
    
    let title: String
    let angle: Double
    
    var body: some View {
        if abs(angle) > 90 {
            EmptyView()
        }
        else {
            let sinValue = sin(rad(angle))
            let cosValue = cos(rad(angle))
            Text(title)
                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                .scaleEffect(y: cosValue)
                .offset(y: sinValue * 85)
                .opacity(abs(angle) < 5 ? 1.0 : cosValue/2)
            
        }
    }
    
    func rad(_ number: Double) -> Double {
        return number * .pi / 180
    }
    
}
```

Usage example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var selectedNumber: Int = 3
    
    var body: some View {
        MyPickerView(Array(0...20), $selectedNumber)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

More simple use:

.accentColor(your color)

```
Picker("", selection: $selected) {
    ForEach(0 ..< data.count) {
        Text(data[$0])
    }
}
.accentColor(.black)
```